# independently generated vs. iid

Tags: probability, independence

I've seen in some texts; given a random variable $X$, independently generate a copy of $X$ denoted by $Y$. What's the difference between this and just saying "let $X,Y$ be i.i.d"?

They seem identical to me, since if the original probability space is not big enough and I want to generate an independent random variable, I can just move up to the product space?

Comment: Not sure what "independently generate a copy of $X$" means.  If it just means that we have $X,Y$ i.i.d then I'd say that instead.

Comment: https://www.math.toronto.edu/joaqsan/Resources/tomas_april2.pdf 
This is the link, page 14 when they define $\omega_{p,i}$.

Comment: you omitted relevant context.  The extended passage reads ", use each random variable $\omega_p$  to generate N
independent copies $\omega_{p,i }$ from the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$".  So these variables have some connection to some other tandom variables.

Comment: To be sure, I think this is poorly phrased (though I didn't read the whole paper so maybe broader context clarifies things).  Copies of what?  What does "from the uniform distribution" mean?  And what does "generate" mean?  are we just talking about an index set or is there some deeper meaning?  Like I say, more context might clarify.

Comment: Ah, that's a Physics text, not Stochastics.  Physicists tend to be less than formal with their applied mathematics.

Comment: the thing is that the collection $(\omega_p)_{p\leq r}$ are i.i.d uniform (so they use both i.i.d and independently generated). If I generated $N$ copies of $\omega_p$ for each $p\leq r$, wouldn't they still be i.i.d? The text this is based off of is Intro to SK models by Pachenko who is a mathematician. Hence, my confusion.

Comment: But that's the confusion, not the linguistic one.  The way I read it, $N$ independent copies of the uniform distribution are labeled be $\omega_p$.  But maybe not!  It's very poorly phrased.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the difference between this and just saying "let $X,Y$ be i.i.d"?

None really, except *perhaps* the concept of '*independent and identically distributed*' has not been introduced at that point in the text.  That, or the author would prefer being overly verbose rather than using a t.l.a., maybe?

Comment: They've already mentioned i.i.d. on page $14$.